# Собрать apk через ant

Tags: ant, android, java

Доброго времени суток. Мне необходимо собрать мой проект используя `ant`, а именно на выход получить apk файл. Использую `IntelliJ IDEA 12`. В интернете практически нет информации о том, как собирать apk через ant, возможно, я плохо искал, не знаю...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Держите полный Ant скрипт для сборки Android приложения написанный лично мной:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<project name="MyProject" default="zipalign" basedir=".">
<property name="target" value="android-8"/>
<!--property file="default.properties" /-->
<property name="encoding" value="UTF-8"/>

<!-- dirs -->
<property name="sdk.dir" location="Location of Android SDK"/>
<property name="proguard.dir" value="proguard" />
<property name="src.dir" value="src"/>
<property name="gen.dir" value="gen"/>
<property name="res.dir" value="res"/>
<property name="assets.dir" value="assets"/>
<property name="libs.dir" value="libs"/>
<property name="out.classes.unoptimized.dir" value="out"/>
<property name="out.classes.optimized.dir" value="out/optimized"/>

<!-- files -->
<property name="manifest.file" value="AndroidManifest.xml"/>
<property name="signed.apk" value="${ant.project.name}-signed.apk"/>
<property name="unsigned.apk" value="${ant.project.name}-unsigned.apk"/>
<property name="final.apk" value="${ant.project.name}.apk"/>
<property name="android.jar" value="${sdk.dir}/tools/platforms/${target}/android.jar"/>
<property name="unoptimized" value="unoptimized.jar" />
<property name="optimized" value="optimized.jar" />
<property name="proguard.config" value="${proguard.dir}/proguard.cfg"/>

<!-- tools -->
<property name="dx.jar" value="${sdk.dir}/platform-tools/lib/dx.jar"/>
<property name="aapt" value="${sdk.dir}/platforms/${target}/tools/aapt.exe"/>
<property name="zipalign" value="${sdk.dir}/tools/zipalign.exe"/>
<property name="jarsign" value="jarsigner.exe location is here"/>
<property name="keystore" value="Your key store is here"/>
<property name="keyalias" value="Your key alias is here"/>

<path id="android.antlibs">
    <pathelement path="${sdk.dir}/tools/lib/anttasks.jar" />
    <pathelement path="${sdk.dir}/tools/lib/sdklib.jar" />
    <pathelement path="${sdk.dir}/tools/lib/androidprefs.jar" />
    <pathelement path="${sdk.dir}/tools/lib/apkbuilder.jar" />
    <pathelement path="${sdk.dir}/tools/lib/jarutils.jar" />
</path>

<taskdef name="setup"
    classname="com.android.ant.SetupTask"
    classpathref="android.antlibs" />
<setup import="false"/>

<!--taskdef name="aaptexec"
        classname="com.android.ant.AaptExecLoopTask"
        classpathref="android.antlibs" /-->

<target name="clean" description="Removes output files created by other targets.">
    <echo>Cleaning...</echo>
    <delete dir="${out.classes.unoptimized.dir}" verbose="true" />
    <delete dir="${out.classes.optimized.dir}" verbose="true" />
</target>

<target name="dirs">
    <echo>Creating output directories if needed...</echo>
    <mkdir dir="${out.classes.unoptimized.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${out.classes.optimized.dir}" />
</target>

<!-- Compiles this project's .java files into .class files. -->
<target name="compile" depends="dirs"
        description="Compiles project's .java files into .class files">
    <echo>Compiling sources...</echo>
    <javac encoding="${encoding}" target="1.6" debug="true" extdirs=""
            destdir="${out.classes.unoptimized.dir}"
            bootclasspathref="android.target.classpath"
            includeantruntime="true">
        <src path="${src.dir}" />
        <src path="${gen.dir}" />
        <classpath>
            <fileset dir="${libs.dir}" includes="*.jar" />
        </classpath>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="preobfuscate" depends="compile">
    <echo>Preparing to obfuscation...</echo>
<jar destfile="${unoptimized}"
   basedir="${out.classes.unoptimized.dir}"
   includes="**/**"
   excludes="optimized/**"
   />
</target>

<!--  Obfuscation with ProGuard   -->
<target name="optimize" unless="nooptimize" depends="preobfuscate">
    <echo>Proguard obfuscation...</echo>
    <java jar="${proguard.dir}/proguard.jar" fork="true" failonerror="true">
        <jvmarg value="-Dmaximum.inlined.code.length=16" />
        <arg value="@${proguard.dir}/proguard.cfg" />
        <arg value="-injars ${unoptimized}" />
        <arg value="-outjars ${optimized}" />
        <arg value="-libraryjars ${android.jar}" />
    </java>
    <unzip src="${optimized}" dest="${out.classes.optimized.dir}" />
    <!-- Delete optimized jar (now unzipped into bin directory)  -->
    <delete file="${optimized}"/>
    <delete file="${unoptimized}"/>
</target>

<target name="dex" description="Converting JVM bytecodes into Dalvik bytecodes" depends="optimize">
    <echo>Converting bytecodes to Dalvik VM bytecodes...</echo>
    <java jar="${dx.jar}" fork="true">
        <arg line="--dex --verbose --output=${out.classes.optimized.dir}/classes.dex ${out.classes.optimized.dir}"/>
    </java>
</target>

<target name="aapt" depends="dex" description="compile resources">
    <echo>Packing resources...</echo>
    <exec executable="${aapt}" logerror="true" osfamily="windows">
        <arg line="p
        -f
        -M ${manifest.file}
        -I ${android.jar}
        -S ${res.dir}
        -A ${assets.dir}
        -F ${out.classes.optimized.dir}/${unsigned.apk}
        -m -J ${gen.dir}"/>
    </exec>
</target>

<target name="sign" depends="aapt" description="sign apk">
    <input message="Please enter keystore password (store:${keystore}):"
                   addproperty="keystore.password" />
    <echo>Signing apk...</echo>
    <exec executable="${jarsign}" logerror="true" osfamily="windows">
        <arg line="-verbose
        -keystore ${keystore}
        -storepass ${keystore.password}
        -signedjar ${out.classes.optimized.dir}/${signed.apk}
        ${out.classes.optimized.dir}/${unsigned.apk} ${keyalias}"/>
    </exec>
</target>

<target name="zipalign" depends="sign" description="zip align">
    <echo>Aligning apk...</echo>
    <exec executable="${zipalign}" logerror="true" osfamily="windows">
        <arg line="-f
        -v
        4
        ${out.classes.optimized.dir}/${signed.apk}
        ${final.apk}"/>
    </exec>
</target>
</project>
```

Он собирает, обфусцирует, сжимает и подписывает `apk`

Comment: Прибольщущее спасибо!

Comment: Почему у меня в сдк нет некоторых из этих библиотек? anttasks.jar, sdklib.jar, androidprefs.jar, apkbuilder.jar, jarutils.jar

Comment: @dexter было написано года 2-3 назад еще под старые тулзы, сейчас все поменялось, так что надо искать, копаться... Как вариант возьмите скачайте старый SDK Tools (что-то типа для GingerBread - API=10) соберите под ним - должно заработать.

Comment: @dexter, чем вас не устраивает в качестве основы ant-скрипт, генерируемый утилитой `android`, входящей в состав SDK? И уже отталкиваясь от него, можете затачивать под свою задачу.

Answer (score 4):

> В интернете практически нет информации о том, как собирать apk через ant

Очень интересно. Однако, почему-то мне, по простейшему запросу "android ant" вываливается куча релевантных ссылок.

Лишь некоторые из них:

- [Автоматическая сборка Android-проектов в Ant](http://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/60161/)
- [Автоматическое генерирование APK с различными данными из командной строки с помощью Ant](http://habrahabr.ru/post/122528/)

А так же, как ни странно, официальная [документация](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html).